# I'm making a blog and need to sort by date

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I'm making a personal blog and I need to sort by date by it comes out as old to new
Here is my code

```
@section('title', 'Posts', 'date')

@section('content')
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <p> See My Blog Posts Here </p>

    <ul>
        @forelse ($posts->sortBy('date') as $post)
            <li>
                <a href="{{ $post->getPath() }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                <small>{{ $post->prettyDate() }}</small>
            </li>
        @empty
            <p>No posts to show.</p>
        @endforelse
    </ul>
@endsection
```

I need help reversing the objects when they come out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [sortByDesc()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortbydesc) to get the result in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to sort laravel collections you can use:

1. `sortBy()`
2. `sortByDesc()`

You can also check here: [Laravel Collection Avilable Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods)

So you can use `$posts->sortByDesc('date')`